# Error connecting to the Google API with Python

Tags: python, api

Its the first time I'am trying to connect to an API. For my example I used the simple Google API with the following code:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://google.com/')
print(response)
```

I received the following error....

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CD3210B888>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: Looks like bad internet connection. Worked for me.

Comment: @PuneetSingh What worked for you?

Comment: I didn't receive any error while executing your code. Disconnecting my internet produced the same error that you mentioned. This error also comes when you are not authorized to access an api which does not seem to be the case here.